# convert fcm notification response in json

Tags: php, android, json

```
Bundle
[{
    google.sent_time=1487229288769,
    gcm.notification.created_at=2017-02-16 12:44:52,
    gcm.notification.e=1,
    gcm.notification.Content_available=1,
    gcm.notification.badge=1,
    gcm.notification.title=, from=388143837768,
    google.message_id=0:1487229288775757%19aca14d19aca14d,
    gcm.notification.body=hi, 
    gcm.notification.uid=160,
    collapse_key=com.sid.Smessenger
}]
```

I am getting above response from fcm and I want to convert it into json
please check above android code.

getting response from remoteMessage.
I am not getting data in getBody().
getting null value only.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "FROM: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    remoteMessage.getFrom();

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) 
        {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) 
       {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message body:" +  
        remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        String questionId =  
        remoteMessage.getData().get("gcm.notification.gid");
        String userId = 
        remoteMessage.getData().get("gcm.notification.uid");
        Log.e("Group ID", questionId);
        Log.e("U ID", userId);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :
        remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
            bundle.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            Log.e(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

            //run it/// and get notification///
        }
        // String created_at = remoteMessage.
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    // String value = bundle.getString("request");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your response snippet, I believe your talking about how should you do it on Android.

> It is in JSON but wrapped in your data bundle, that you have received as
>   argument in FCM receiver function try getting values from your bundle, as
>   usually we do in android.
>
> Rather than thinking "JSON", think "key/value pairs". Your server
>   sends data in key/value pairs. Your app receives that data as
>   key/value pairs in the extras in the Intent you get. You know what your keys
>   are, so just retrieve the values out of the extras that are tied to
>   those keys (e.g., getStringExtra("message"), getStringExtra("title"))

Hope this solves your prob.

Comment: hello i am beginner in andriod, please can u explain briefly??

Comment: I'm not here to write code for you, read the docs for JSON and Intent Bundle about how to parse them. I have shown you the way now put some efforts, don't expect spoon feeding here...

Comment: zzahb= "Bundle[{google.sent_time// some above response//  collapse_key=com.sid.Smessenger}]

Comment: do one thing add your code to the question, where you are receiving and getting this intent.